# Unable to install Zoneminder on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, zoneminder

I've tried to follow the instructions in the following two links, but to no avail:

http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/Ubuntu_12.04/13.04_Desktop
http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/Ubuntu_Server_12.04_64-bit_with_Zoneminder_1.26.5_the_easy_way

After finishing all the steps, I would restart, but then the computer hangs on the Ubuntu loading screen. I can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>  and log in via terminal, but obviously I need a GUI for a surveillance system, forcing me to reinstall Ubuntu.

Even if I don't restart, despite the fact that during the installation of Zoneminder, it showed that the program has started, I do not see it when going to either localhost (it shows the default apache page), or localhost/vm (shows a 404).

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I've got no idea what to do, or what other alternatives there are to ZM that I could try. Personally, I'm looking for whatever works. If I can't solve this problem easily, I would prefer to simply install an alternative program.

Also, I recall reading something about there being PHP/SQL issues for this release of Ubuntu due to deprecated code (I assume the switch over to PDO in PHP). That might explain things, but again, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The links you provided were for Ubuntu 12.04. Please use: http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/Ubuntu_Server_14.04_64-bit_with_Zoneminder_1.26.5_the_easy_way  I have verified that this works on Ubuntu server. You will not get a GUI on the PC but you can access the ZM server from another PC. Running ZM on a Ubuntu desktop does work but there are some errors that pop up when you log into the desktop. From time to time well meaning folks will change my write ups and that confuses people who do not know a lot about Ubuntu or Linux. bb

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and execute following commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Add Zoneminder Repository

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:iconnor/zoneminder
sudo apt-get update
```

Install Zoneminder

```
sudo apt-get install zoneminder
```

Create a file called zoneminder.conf

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/tmpfiles.d/zoneminder.conf
```

Paste or enter the following to above file

```
d /var/run/zm 0755 www-data www-data
```

Then save the file

Change permissions on the file

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/tmpfiles.d/zoneminder.conf
```

Create a symbolic link

```
sudo ln -s /etc/zm/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/zoneminder.conf
```

Create a new user

```
sudo adduser www-data video
```

Restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Download `cambozola tar.gz` file from the following link  and extract it to the home folder 
http://www.charliemouse.com/code/cambozola/

Then open the terminal and execute
    sudo cp cambozola-0.936/dist/cambozola.jar /usr/share/zoneminder

Then open the web browser `http://localhost/zm/`

Now you can add monitor and make your webcam a cctv camera .
If the camera doesn't work restart zoneminder using the start/stop button at the top 
of ZM -Console.

Answer (score 0):

It just simple and easy to install `zoneminder` in ubuntu.

it is in the [Official Ubuntu Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=zoneminder&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all).

```
 sudo apt-get install zoneminder
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me with error `BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/zmpkg.pl line 37`

Comment: Had to start **MySQL**.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have problems with your computer 
Here it worked! [Zoneminder - Guida Installaz. passo x passo](http://forum.ubuntu-it.org/viewtopic.php?f=75&t=582389&sid=ef7a755da8c27fd349010a18f134f21f)

If your system has got too many installations Zoneminder and LAMP (Linux Apache MySQL PHP)
[Azzerare e pulire tutto per DISINSTALLARE LAMP ( Linux, Apache, MySQL e PHP)](http://forum.ubuntu-it.org/viewtopic.php?f=75&t=582389&p=4613428#p4613428)

Or try on a virtual machine with VirtualBox clean, as was done in this guide.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. In general it is better if you can provide a brief description of what's involved in the proposed solution and then provide the link for reference and attribution purposes. This way if the link(s) become unavailable for whatever reason, your answer will remain helpful.